# Python: scipy.sparse slower than numpy.matmul for sparse matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse matrix with more than 50% sparse entries. I am trying to compute its matrix multiplication with itself using scipy.sparse and numpy.matmul. Ironically numpy.matmul gives lesser multiplication time than scipy.sparse on both dense and sparse matrices.

```
 import scipy
 import time
 start=time.time()
 SS=scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(grad_shaped)*scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(numpy.transpose(grad_shaped))
 SS1=SS.todense()
 end=time.time()
 print(end-start)

 start=time.time()
 SS2=numpy.matmul(grad_shaped[0],numpy.transpose(grad_shaped[0]))
 end=time.time()
 print(end-start)
```

I have float data matrix. The zeros are present as 0.0. Does it make any difference leading to more time? I have tried it with varying size of matrices. As the matrix size increases, still numpy.matmul is faster than scipy.sparse.csr

Comment: So you are starting with a dense array.  In one you convert to sparse, multiply, and convert back.  In the other you just do the multiply.  Making a sparse matrix takes time, especially since you do it for both arguments.  By itself (without the timing the conversions), I find that sparse multiply is faster only if the sparsity is 10% or less.

Comment: @hpaulj I have two separate arrays of same size. One is dense and the other has more than 50% locations from the dense array replaced by 0.

Comment: *"... with more than 50% sparse entries."*  How much more than 50%?  As @hpaulj notes, you are not likely to see any benefit from using a sparse matrix unless a lot more than 50% are zero.

Comment: 70% of the entries closely

Comment: Time `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(grad_shaped)` by itself.

Comment: @hpaulj I have two scripts. One running on dense and other on sparse data. So scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(grad_shaped) should also be timed. But  why the time is not reduced.